# Как определить подсеть клиентского приложения?

Tags: .net

Нужно определять, принадлежат ли клиенты одной подсети, в TcpClient присутствует ip и порт, как вытащить маску подсети?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

1. Пробегитесь по всем сетевым интерфейсам (`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`).
2. Для каждого интерфейса получите `IPInterfaceProperties` через `GetIPProperties()`.
3. Из него получите список `UnicastIPAddressInformation` через свойство `UnicastAddresses`.
4. В каждом из элементов списка есть свойства `Address` и `Mask`. Имея их, можно определить, принадлежит ли ваш TcpClient данной подсети.

Дальше самоочевидно.

Comment: Нужно определить, лежат ли в одной подсети два клиента, а не клиент и сервер.

Comment: Вы об удалённом конце соединения? Если так, то вам неоткуда взять топологию сети на другом конце интернета, решения нет. Можно лишь придумать эвристику, например, предположить, что у них там сеть класса `C`.

Comment: Действительно, мой пробел в знаниях по сетям. Что в итоге нужно было мне - определять, есть ли подключения с одного ip по разным портам.

Comment: @WarHamster: а, ну отлично, тогда проблема решена.